# Storing Discord API access tokens in the database?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, discord, access-token, bearer-token

I'm building an app that uses the Discord OAuth2 API to check a user's roles. Making a request requires an access token.

Currently, I've stored the refresh token in my app's MongoDB database, and use that to fetch a fresh access token each time to make the request. (fetching a new access token also requires my app's client id and client secret, which are .env variables)

I'm wondering if it would make sense to also store the access token and the expiry time, so that I don't have to fetch a new access token each time, only when it expires. Are there any security concerns with doing it this way?